# Remote Login to Windows and execute commands in command prompt using PowerShell

Tags: powershell-2.0, remoting, command-prompt, remote-access

I have to remotely log in to a particular server (say server A) from a remote location (Say server B) and execute commands like ping,telnet (to server C) in the command prompt of server A and return the command output to server B and perform few steps based on these outputs.I have script to do manipulation for the output retrieved and script to invoke command prompt.but executing the required commands and connecting to the remote machine is a problem.

All the three servers A, B and C are in the same domain.I have admin rights to all the servers.Another problem is enabling remoting on the server A is not possible as server A will be a client server (100s of them taken one at a time) and hence enabling  remoting on each of the client server will be a tedious task. Any other possibility of accessing other than enabling remoting.the solution may be simple but I am new to PowerShell and hence couldnt find any way to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

Remoting is the appropriate way to do this. It should not be difficult or tedious to enable remoting across many machines if you use your system management software (SCCM/SCOM, for example) or possibly AD logon scripts.

You will need to watch out for the "double hop problem", which is mitigated [by using CredSSP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/06/25/9803001.aspx).